# PHP application/x-www-form-urlencoded decodes special character wrongly

Tags: php, post, utf-8

A remote SMS service (I cannot influence) POSTs text messages to a PHP-controller (of a Symfony2 app if that matters) as Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

PHP cannot decode special characters correctly.

a tcpdump shows (abbreviated - only showing the data in question )

```
User-Agent: smsd (libwww-perl/5.805)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 123

data=ae+%E4+ue+%FC+oe+%F6+sz+%DF
```

The original data was

```
ae ä ue ü oe ö sz ß
```

and the PHP $_POST holds (serialized)

```
;s:4:"data";s:19:"ae ###e ###### sz ##;
```

I suppose, it is the missing charset=UTF-8, that causes the troubles.

If anyone has an idea how to overcome this, I'd appreciate your answer. Thanx.

Comment: Why are you serializing it?

Comment: I think he just did that to show us the raw contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this specific problem I now found a solution myself using iconv.

```
$decoded = iconv( 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', urldecode( $encoded ) );
```

I think the standard charset being used for urlencode/urldecode in PHP >= 5.4 is now UTF-8, although I didn't find anything in the changelogs for these functions specifically.

Comment: To elaborate on my answer a little further: It is NOT a missing charset=UTF-8 in the header that is causing the problem obviously but the implicit usage of UTF-8 in PHP since 5.4. Maybe an explicit charset=ISO-8859-1 in the header would help though...